# XPath query in an XPath query

Tags: php, html, xpath

how can a start a second and third XPatch query in an XPatch query?
For example

CodePad = http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZhMNGw

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="entries">                               
    <h3 class="headline" style="position: relative; cursor: pointer;">
        <div>
            <a class="selink" href="/tste/?sd=28726585">  
                <span class="date"> 10:15 </span> 
                <span class="titel">THE TITLE<span class="subtitel">some subtitle</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>                              
    </h3>
</div>  
<div class="entries">                               
    <h3 class="headline" style="position: relative; cursor: pointer;">
        <div>
            <a class="selink" href="/tste/?sd=287265995">  
                <span class="date"> 10:16 </span> 
                <span class="titel">THE TITLE 2<span class="subtitel">some subtitle</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>                              
    </h3>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://domain.com/startpage.php');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='entries']"; // <- QUERY ONE

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
$list = array();

$count = 0;
foreach ($entries as $key => $value)
{        
    $list[$count] = array();

    // get the link <- QUERY TWO
    $list[$count]['url'] =  $xpath->query("//a[@class='selink']");

    // get the title but NOT the subtitle <- QUERY THREE
    $list[$count]['title'] = $xpath->query("//span[@class='titel']");


    $count++;
}


print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xpath->query($expr) is executed on the whole document each call within the loop because you don't pass the document node the XPath query should be evaluated in relatively.

With the polymorphic method [DOMNodeList query(string $expr, DOMNode $node)](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) you can do a sub query relative to the given $node.
This method produces the desired result only if you use a relative XPath $expr (without leading /).
To retrieve the string from each DOMNode/TextNode finally use the queries as follows:

```
$list[$count]['url'] = $xpath->query("h3/div/a[@class='selink']/@href", $value)->item(0)->value;
$list[$count]['title'] = $xpath->query("h3/div/a/span[@class='titel']/text()", $value)->item(0)->wholeText;
```

I edited your CodePad code [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G5W0SC).

regards,
Max

Comment: I dont get it. Can you please edit my codepad demo? http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZhMNGw

Comment: Sorry, I just realised each query starts with the document root. Instead you should use relative sub queries. I adjusted my answer respectively.